# MongoDB - Hosting on multiple servers

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, replication, norm

I am wanting to use MongoDB on my Windows Server and I am using the .NET code at:

```
https://github.com/atheken/NoRM/wiki/
```

I have 2 web servers that I need to host MongoDB on and keep the database on both instances in sync. What should I be looking at to accomplish this? It seems the master/slave replication option is ideal.

If I do this, can I keep my connection string as?

```
mongodb://localhost/MyDatabase?strict=false
```

Thanks for any help. This is my first attempt as using MongoDB.

Comment: Why do you need two servers, if I may ask?

Comment: We have 2 web servers and a load balancer. The goal is that if traffic hits our primary web server, it will hit the main MongoDB database, else, it will go the slave. If data is inserted on the slave, I want it replicated to the master.

Comment: You can't do that, MongoDB doesn't support bidirectional replication. Master/slave means you can only write to the master and then read from either the master or the slave. If you're trying to spread writes across multiple servers, you want sharding, if you're only trying to spread reads, then master/slave replication is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support this kind of peer-to-peer replication, only master-slave where data is always written to a primary database then sync'd out to secondary replicas.  You can, however, distribute reads across the replicas by using the `slaveOk` option.  Check out **replica sets** for more info.  To distribute writes, take a look at **sharding**.

Also, it might not be ideal to host MongoDB and your web server on the same box.  Mongo is greedy when it comes to memory, and if the database grows larger than available RAM then web server performance could really suffer.

Comment: The sharding and automatic failover options are what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This tutorial was great to help me get setup and running: http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/08/03/automating-partitioning-sharding-and-failover-with-mongodb/

Comment: No probs, some really excellent MongoDB tips on the blog, and their Server Density is a great product.